# Multipart Rest based Java spring web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, multipart

Im new to java based web service development.
I need to create a web service which accepts multipart data(ex: zip file).
Please help me out how to mention that in the function.

below is my current web service code which is accepting data in the form of json.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/workitems/updateData", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object updateData(@RequestHeader String deviceToken, @RequestBody FormFields[]      
formFields,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

//some code
}
```

please guide me to how to accept the multipart data in the web service method.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick pointer to the docs: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(
value ="/workitems/updateData",method=RequestMethod.POST ,headers="Accept=application/xml, application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    Object updateData(HttpServletResponse response,@RequestHeader String deviceToken,
            @RequestParam ("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {



}
```

You can support it as above.

Comment: changed as above .. 
But i am now getting a 400 - bad request error
client:
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload a file please</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8081/meap/infoimage/ver11/workitems/updateData" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: You have to upload a file when calling this url. that is mandatory. Or else you have to define request param as required false

Comment: im also using a rest client to do this, and selecting a file. but still getting bad request error.

Comment: how you upload the file using rest client? try using a html like <html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload a file please</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
        <form method="post" action="your url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Now i am getting 400 - Token not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal Upload technique which you use in Servlet - commons-fileupload.jar way.

The same code placed in a method inside your controller will work fine. Make sure you pass `HttpServletRequest` object to your method.